# 401 Unauthorized only when on server

Tags: c#, iis, iis-7, restsharp

Problem: This code works fine from my local machine, but NOT on the server itself. (E.G. I can run this Linqpad script from my machine, I get a 200 and some data. I copy it to the server where the app is hosted and I get a 401. Why!? App has Windows Auth only enabled, NTLM only.

```
//Create REST client
var client = new RestClient("https://app.com/service/")
                {
                    //Windows Auth
                    Authenticator = new NtlmAuthenticator("test\\test", "9#@903f")
                };

//Create Request to be sent             
var request = new RestRequest("api/dogs/furriest");

//Create params to send
var parameters = new        {
    FurryLevel = 1,
    CuteLevel = 2
};

//Add params to request
request.AddParameter("application/json", parameters.ToJson(), ParameterType.RequestBody);

//Execute the request
var response = client.ExecuteAsPost(request, "POST");
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you enable windows authentication on your IIS site ?

Comment: Yes that is the only allowed form of authentication at the moment.